# How can I create an iMacros that autopost on facebook?

Tags: imacros

I have a facebook page for my business. I want to be able to write and save all the posts of one day in 10 minutes and lunch an imacro that will post them one by one every 30 minutes .
I searched in google and found out that iMacros is the easiest way.

How can I create an iMacros that autopost on facebook ?
Where should I start ? thank you.

Comment: This is a good start: http://wiki.imacros.net/Main_Page

Comment: Thank you but I still think I need further help.

Comment: Start with recording a small macro. For what you described you need JavaScript code. I made scripts like these and they are not free.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var contents = null, images = null, groups = null;
var codedefault1="TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS\n SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO\n SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10\n SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\n SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0.1\n";
var codedefault2="SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO\n SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10\n SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\n SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0.1\n";
var wm             = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var window         = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
function random(a,b){var c= b-a; return Math.floor((Math.random()*c)+a);}
function playPost(groups,contents,images,time1,time2){
    for(key in groups){
        if(typeof(groups[key].href)!="undefined"){
            if(key==0) code="TAB OPEN\n TAB T=2\n";
            else code="";
            code+="URL GOTO=https://m.facebook.com/groups/"+gup('group_id',groups[key].href)+"\n";
            if(images.length==0){
                code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:* CONTENT="+contents[random(0,contents.length-1)].value.replace(/ /g, "<sp>").replace(/\n/g, "<br>")+"\n";
                code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT  ATTR=NAME:view_post\n";
                code+="WAIT SECONDS="+random(10,35)+"\n";
            }else{
                code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT  ATTR=name:lgc_view_photo\n";
                for(key2 in images){
                    if(!isNaN(key2)){
                        code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:file"+(parseInt(key2)+parseInt(1))+" CONTENT="+images[key2].getAttribute('data').replace(/ /g, "<sp>")+"\n";
                    }
                }
                code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:* CONTENT="+contents[random(0,contents.length-1)].value.replace(/ /g, "<sp>").replace(/\n/g, "<br>")+"\n";
                code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=NAME:photo_upload\n";
                code+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=NAME:done\n";
                code+="WAIT SECONDS="+random(time1,time2)+"\n";
            }
            iimPlayCode(codedefault2+code);
        } 
    }
}

function gup( name, url ) {
  if (!url) url = location.href
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( url );
  return results == null ? null : results[1];
}

function getParents(el) {
    var parents = [];
    var p = el.parentNode;
    while (p !== null) {
        var o = p;
        parents.push(o);
        p = o.parentNode;
    }
    return parents;
}
iimPlayCode(codedefault1+"URL GOTO=http://sozi.vn\n TAB OPEN\n TAB T=2\n URL GOTO=https://m.facebook.com/settings/notifications/groups/\n ");
window.document.querySelectorAll("#header")[0].innerHTML='<div class="contentap"><div class="ctap"><textarea style="width:98%" placeholder="Content" class="ap"></textarea></div></div>      <div class="btcta" style="float:right;"><button class="act">add content</button><button class="rmct">Remove Content</button></div>         <div class="imgap"><input style="width:98%"  type="file" class="upfbgr" data="" > <br><input style="width:98%"  type="file" class="upfbgr" data="" > <br><input style="width:98%"  type="file" class="upfbgr" data="" > <br></div>      <br>  Time Random <input type="text" value="20" style="width:50px;" name="sd">-<input type="text" value="50" style="width:50px;" name="ss">     <div class="btcta" style="float:right;"><button class="editgroup">Edit Group</button><button class="run">RunPost</button></div>'



window.document.querySelectorAll('.rmct')[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.document.querySelectorAll('.ctap')[window.document.querySelectorAll('.ctap').length-1].remove();
});

window.document.querySelectorAll('.act')[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(window.document.querySelectorAll('.ctap').length<3){
        window.document.querySelectorAll('.contentap')[0].innerHTML = window.document.querySelectorAll('.contentap')[0].innerHTML + '<div class="ctap"><textarea style="width:98%" placeholder="Content" class="ap"></textarea></div></div>';
    }
});
for(i in window.document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]') ) 
    if(!isNaN(i)) 
        window.document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]')[i].addEventListener("change", function(){this.setAttribute('data',this.value);});

var edit=0;     
window.document.querySelectorAll('.editgroup')[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(edit==0){
        var gr = window.document.querySelectorAll("h3");
        for(i in gr){
            if(!isNaN(i)){
                gr[i].innerHTML = gr[i].innerHTML +' <button class="rmgr"> Delete</button> ';
                window.document.querySelectorAll("h3 button")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                    getParents(this)[1].remove();
                });

            }   
        } 
        edit=1; 
    }
});
window.document.querySelectorAll('.run')[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    contents = window.document.querySelectorAll(".ap");
    if(contents[0].value!=""){
        images = window.document.querySelectorAll(".upfbgr:not([data=\"\"])");
        groups = window.document.querySelectorAll("h3 a");
        time1 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input[name='sd']")[0].value;
        time2 = window.document.querySelectorAll("input[name='ss']")[0].value;
        playPost(groups,contents,images,time1,time2);
    }else{
        contents[0].style.border="1px solid #C82828";
    }

});
iimPlay('CODE:WAIT SECONDS=9999');
```

Auto post group facebook
+ select all group 
+ random content post
+ random time post
Video youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88BurO3Vvnc